# Spyder app will not launch on OSX

Tags: python, macos, launch, anaconda, spyder

I recently bought a new mac, and I'm having trouble with Anaconda. For some reason, Spyder will not launch. I click the launch-button, and nothing happens. I get the message "Launching spyder-app. Some apps take a moment to start." But then nothing starts.

My computer is running OS X 10.9.5.
Python version: 2.7.9
spyder version 2.3.3

So here's what I've done/tried so far:

- Installed anaconda twice. First time in /anaconda. I now have it installed here: /Users/Madeleine/anaconda
- Next thing I did was update both spyder as well as conda and anaconda.
  (When I tried to use the "conda update conda"-command and "conda update anaconda" in terminal, I got the message "command not found". But I found a soulution to this. I typed "export PATH=/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/bin:$PATH" and then tried again. It worked. So both conda and anaconda are up to date.)

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried running spyder from terminal, and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/bin/spyder", line 2, in <module>
    from spyderlib import start_app
  File "/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib    /start_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from spyderlib.baseconfig import get_conf_path, running_in_mac_app
  File "/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib    /baseconfig.py", line 239, in <module>
    _ = get_translation("spyderlib")
  File "/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib    /baseconfig.py", line 214, in get_translation
    lang = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
  File "/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543,     in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/Madeleine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475,     in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#issue-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-on-mac-os-x